# What is the correct way to load pylab?

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

I have seen two methods for loading pylab:

```
get_ipython().magic(u'pylab inline')
```

and

```
%pylab inline
```

Are these two methods equivalent?  If not, how do I decide which method to use?

Comment: I would still encourage you reading [this](https://carreau.github.io/posts/10-No-PyLab-Thanks.html). Although `pylab` is nice for transition from matlab-like enviroments, it is kinda dangerous if you don't really know **exactly** what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent.

`get_ipython()` returns an instance of `InteractiveShell`. The [documentation](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html#IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell.magic) of the `InteractiveShell.magic()` method says:

> magic(‘name -opt foo bar’) is equivalent to typing at the ipython
>   prompt:
>
> In[ 1]: %name -opt foo bar

Also note that the `magic` function is deprecated and the function `run_line_magic` should be used instead.